# Offline web application app cache

Tags: html, indexeddb, offline-caching

I am about to start, working on a offline web application using HTML5, indexed db.
I have been reading a lot about it. But I got little confused thinking if the user deletes the cache of the browser, my app cache would also got deleted. And then there would be no way to use the application offline, until we got connected to internet, and browser creates a fresh cache.

Is this assumption true..or Is there a way to protect the app cache from getting deleted accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

#### No. There isn't.

This is a normal behaviour which is similar to mobile apps. If users've removed their native apps, they need to redownload them whenever they want to reuse those apps. Appcache is not a silver bullet for the case.